# Python how to browse a nested list/tuple keeping the hierarchy

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of this kind:

```
lista = """
<ul>
<li>Arts &amp; Entertainment
<ul>
  <li>Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News</li>
  <li>Comics &amp; Animation
    <ul>
    <li>Anime &amp; Manga</li>
    <li>Cartoons</li>
    <li>Comics</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>

"""
```

which through Beautiful Soup was converted in this kind of mix of tuple and lists:

```
[(u'Arts &amp; Entertainment',
  [u'Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News',
   (u'Comics &amp; Animation',
    [u'Anime &amp; Manga', u'Cartoons', u'Comics'])])]
```

In order to list all the elements keeping the hierarchi I was trying something like this:

```
myLevel = 0
def orderList2(item):
    global myLevel
    for i in item:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            print str(myLevel) + " " + str(i.encode("utf-8")) + " tuple <br/>"            
        elif isinstance(i, tuple):  
            print str(myLevel) + " " + str(i[0].encode("utf-8")) + " tuple <br/>"
        orderList2(item)
```

but it actually doesn't really work...

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you never change `myLevel`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def orderList2(item, level=0):
    for i in item:
        if isinstance(i, basestring):
            print level, i.encode('utf-8'), 'tuple <br />'
        elif isinstance(i, tuple):
            orderList2(i, level)
        else:
            orderList2(i, level+1)
```

Here is the output for your data:

```
>>> item = [(u'Arts &amp; Entertainment', [u'Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News', (u'Comics &amp; Animation', [u'Anime &amp; Manga', u'Cartoons', u'Comics'])])]
>>> orderList2(item)
0 Arts &amp; Entertainment tuple <br />
1 Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News tuple <br />
1 Comics &amp; Animation tuple <br />
2 Anime &amp; Manga tuple <br />
2 Cartoons tuple <br />
2 Comics tuple <br />
```

Note that instead of using a global level variable, this just passes in the current level to use in the recursion.  Also, in your version the recursive call was `orderList2(item)`, when you probably meant to call it with `i`.  Instead of printing the first item in tuples, this will instead just make a recursive call with the same level, and with lists it will make a recursive call and increment the level.  Finally, instead of checking `isinstance(i, str)`, it checks for `basestring`, which is necessary since the strings in your data are unicode.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly and you're explanation was really clear.

Comment: @silviolor - No problem, you can [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155356) by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer so that others know your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper function isn't quite right. Try:

```
def orderList2(myLevel, item):
    for i in item:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        print str(myLevel) + " " + str(i.encode("utf-8")) + " tuple <br/>"            
    elif isinstance(i, tuple):
        visit(myLevel + 1, i)
```

That prints out strings and, when it hits a tuple, increments the level and prints out the strings in that tuple, until it hits another tuple, and so and so forth. No need for the globals you have in your OP.

And then call that on your top-level tuple and let it go to town:

```
orderList2(0, item)
```

That lets you handle arbitrary depths of nesting in your markup.